# Spaces in system() C++

Tags: c++, cmd, system, spaces

I've tried with some solutions found in Stackoverflow, but i can't get it to work, i want to start a .LOG (.txt file) from C++, but the path folder containing it might have spaces, so when i try to start it, i get an error saying it cant find the file because the pah (containing spaces) is wrong, here is what my code looks like:

```
void Log (unsigned int Code,...)
{
char currdate[11] = {0};
SYSTEMTIME t;
GetLocalTime(&t);
sprintf(currdate, "%02d:%02d:%02d", t.wHour, t.wMinute, t.wSecond);

PROCESSENTRY32 pe32;
FILE* FileHwnd1;

FileHwnd1 = fopen("TEST.log","a+");
fprintf(FileHwnd1,"[%s] Code: %X\n",currdate,Code);
fclose(FileHwnd1);
char buffer[MAX_PATH];
GetModuleFileName( NULL, buffer, MAX_PATH);
char Path[50];

wsprintf(Path,"start %s\\AntiHack.log",buffer);
system(Path);//Here is where i get the containing spaces path error
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Normally you'd surround the name with spaces in quotation marks.

Answer (score 2):

I would advise you avoid the system call entirely and do the process launch yourself.

1. Use [AssocQueryString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773471%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)() to find the associated process for your
   extension (in this case, .log)
2. Setup and launch a [CreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)() call to invoke, passing the
   appropriate command line.

there are other ways to do this, but as you're noticing now, going a round-about way will always have pitfalls. The above is spot-on with how Explorer.exe launches the associated process for an extension.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
wsprintf(Path,"start \"\" \"%s\"\\\AntiHack.log",buffer);
```

Comment: I think you mean `start \"%s\\AntiHack.log\"`.

Comment: True, but we both missed that you need `start "" "whatever.lol"` if quotations are needed or it will just open a new console window with that as the title (at least in Windows, not sure otherwise). I noticed you fixed the \A issue as well.

Comment: Now it seems to be getting the path correctly, but it happens what Chris said, i only get a new CMD with the path on the title, how should i fix that?. Thanks.

Comment: @PabloLopez, You need a `\"\"` after `start`.

Comment: Ok, i've tried this:

         wsprintf(Path,"start \"\"\"%s\\AntiHack.log\"",buffer);

But it just opens the CMD with the path on the title

Comment: @Pablo: You need a space between the pair of quotes and the quoted command.